# Would someone be able to aggregate my Excel frequency file of 1 million unique Russian word forms into lemmas?

Tags: discussion, resources

Based upon the official Russian Corpus, I have gathered a frequency list of Russian unique word forms on an Excel file (about **840'000** **unique word forms** out of an universe of 188 million words – with и being the most frequent word, with 7'416'716 occurrences), which I have cleaned from non-Russian words.

Would someone be able to generate from this Excel file an aggregated frequency list by lemmas please?

Comment: You may want to try this lemmatizer. It's not production quality yet, but I'm gradually improving it: https://dev5.morpher.ru/lemmy?word=пошли

Comment: Dear @Sergey Slepov, unfortunately I have no programming skills and I am unable to use your lemmatizer.

Comment: Xavier, can you email me your frequency list, I'll see what I can do. sergey@morpher.ru